# How to group by column?

Tags: r, aggregation

I have a dataframe of student scores, instead of getting an overall average score for every student, I need to get the average scores by "course-type" for every student, for example, courses a,c,d are the same type, and courses b, e are the same type. I  do this by the following code, but it is not "R" enough:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), c=c(6,7,8),
                d=c(7,8,9), e=c(10, 11, 12))
group <- data.frame(no=c(1,2,1,1,2), name=c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"))

> x
  a b c d  e
1 1 4 6 7 10
2 2 5 7 8 11
3 3 6 8 9 12

> group
  no name
1  1    a
2  2    b
3  1    c
4  1    d
5  2    e
```

I think this is some stupid:

```
x.1 <- x[,as.character(group$name[group$no==1])]
x.2 <- x[,as.character(group$name[group$no==2])]
mean.by.no <- data.frame(x.1.mean=apply(x.1, 1, mean),
                         x.2.mean=apply(x.2, 1, mean))
```

Answer (score 3):

If `mean.by.no` is the expected result, we could `split` the 'name' column by 'no' ('group' dataset) to get a list.  Using one of`apply` family functions (`lapply/sapply/vapply`), we can use the output as column index for the 'x', and get the mean for each row (`rowMeans`).

```
 vapply(with(group, split(as.character(name), no)),
               function(y) rowMeans(x[y]), numeric(nrow(x)))
 #            1 2
 #[1,] 4.666667 7
 #[2,] 5.666667 8
 #[3,] 6.666667 9
```

Or using `tapply`, we can get the `mean` using grouping index for row and column.

```
indx <- xtabs(no~name, group)[col(x)]
t(tapply(as.matrix(x), list(indx, row(x)), FUN=mean))
#         1 2
#1 4.666667 7
#2 5.666667 8
#3 6.666667 9
```

Or another option would be to convert the 'x' from 'wide' to 'long' format using `melt` from `data.table` after converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`).  Set the key column as 'name' (`setkey(..`), and get the `mean` grouped by 'no' and 'rn' (row number column created by `keep.rownames=TRUE`).  If needed, the output can be converted back to 'wide' format using `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dL <- setkey(melt(setDT(x, keep.rownames=TRUE), id.var='rn', 
     variable.name='name')[, name:= as.character(name)], 
      name)[group[2:1]][,mean(value) , by=list( no, rn)]
dcast(dL, rn~paste0('mean',no), value.var='V1')[,rn:=NULL][]
#      mean1 mean2
#1: 4.666667     7
#2: 5.666667     8
#3: 6.666667     9
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more elegant way of this, but:

```
library(reshape)
library(plyr)
 x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), c=c(6,7,8), d=c(7,8,9), e=c(10, 11, 12))
 group <- data.frame(no=c(1,2,1,1,2), name=c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"))

a<-melt(x)
names(a)<-c("name", "score")
b<-merge(a, group, by="name")
c<-ddply(b, c("no"), summarize, meanscore=mean(score))
c

> c
  no meanscore
1  1  5.666667
2  2  8.000000
```

Comment: To use "melt" is a clear and clean way to the solution. But I think you misunderstand the question. :-)